# Google IAP testing requires application from Play Store specifically

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have created a Google IAP project and set up all the products and testers in Console Account. Now at the testing phase, Do i need that application through Google Play Store? or Can i use a signed version of application via my PC?

Comment: If the app is published then you can install the apk through pc and purchase subscriptions